# 1's complement using ~ in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, unsigned, signed, ones-complement

I am using Visual Studio 2013.
Recently I tried the `~` operator for 1's complement:

```
int a = 10;
cout << ~a << endl;
```

Output is `-11`

But for

```
unsigned int a = 10;
cout << ~a << endl;
```

the output is `4294967296`

I don't get why the output is `-11` in the case of signed `int`.
Please help me with this confusion.

Comment: You flip the sign bit as well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you put number 10 into 32-bit signed or unsigned integer, you get

```
0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 1010
```

When you negate it, you get

```
1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 0101
```

These 32 bits mean 4294967285 as an unsigned integer, or -11 as a signed integer (your computer represents negative integers as [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)). They can also mean a 32-bit floating point number or four 8-bit characters.

Bits don't have any "absolute" meaning. They can represent anything, depending on how you "look" at them (which type they have).

Answer (score 4):

The `~` operator performs a [ones-complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) on its argument, and it does not matter whther the argument is a signed or unsigned integer. It merely flips all the bits, so

```
0000 0000 0000 1010 (bin) / 10 (dec)
```

becomes

```
1111 1111 1111 0101 (bin)
```

(where, presumably, these numbers are 32 bits wide -- I omitted 16 more 0's and 1's.)

How will `cout` display the result? It looks at the original type. For a *signed* integer, the most significant bit is its sign. Thus, the result is always going to be *negative* (because the most significant bit in `10` is `0`). To display a negative number as a positive one, you need the two's complement: inverting all bits, then add 1. For example, `-1`, binary `111..111`, displays as (inverting) `000..000` then +1: `000..001`. Result: `-1`.

Applying this to the one's complement of `10` you get `111..110101` -> inverting to `000...001010`, then add `1`. Result: -11.

For an *unsigned* number, `cout` doesn't do this (naturally), and so you get a large number: the largest possible integer *minus* the original number.

Answer (score 2):

In memory there is stored 4294967285 in both cases (4294967296 properly a typo, 33 bit?), the meaning of this number depends which signdeness you use:

- if it's signed, this the number is -11.
- if it's unsigned, then it's 4294967285

different interpretations of the same number.

You can reinterpret it as unsigned by casting it, same result:

```
int a = 10;
cout << (unsigned int) ~a << endl;
```

Comment: the above code is returning -11 for 10

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
unsigned int getOnesComplement(unsigned int number){

unsigned onesComplement = 1;
if(number < 1)
    return onesComplement;
size_t size = (sizeof(unsigned int) * 8 - 1) ;
unsigned int oneShiftedToMSB = 1 << size;

unsigned int shiftedNumber = number;
for ( size_t bitsToBeShifted = 0; bitsToBeShifted < size; bitsToBeShifted++){
    shiftedNumber = number << bitsToBeShifted;
    if(shiftedNumber & oneShiftedToMSB){
        onesComplement = ~shiftedNumber;
        onesComplement = onesComplement >> bitsToBeShifted;
        break;
    }
}
return onesComplement;
}
```